# Make a developed function in a custom odoo 9 module work in odoo 11

Tags: python-3.5, odoo-11

I'm using odoo 11 and I want to create a custom module to add stamp tax in each invoice automatically. I have such module developped in odoo 9 but it does not work in odoo 11 after installing it. Here is the code of python (v2.7) file:

```
from openerp import tools
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class res_partner(osv.osv):
_name = "res.company"
_inherit = "res.company"
_columns = {
    "default_stamp_tax_account": fields.many2one('account.account', "stamp tax account"),
    "default_stamp_tax_value": fields.float('stamp tax value'),
}


class account_invoice(osv.osv):
_name = "account.invoice"
_inherit = "account.invoice"

 def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
     invoice_id = super(account_invoice, self).create(cr, uid, values, context)

     res_company = self.pool.get('res.company')

     stamp_account = res_company.browse(cr, uid, values.get('company_id')).default_stamp_tax_account.id
     tax_value = res_company.browse(cr, uid, values.get('company_id')).default_stamp_tax_value

     if stamp_account:
         account_invoice_tax = self.pool.get('account.invoice.tax')

         tax_line_values = {'base': 0,
                            'amount': tax_value,
                            'name': 'Timbre',
                            'account_id': stamp_account,
                            'invoice_id': invoice_id
                            }

         account_invoice_tax.create(cr, uid, tax_line_values)

     return invoice_id
```

Any help please !!!

Comment: Hi Edwige. Is there any console error when you try to execute the function?

Comment: Hi Lucas. No, there is no any console error even when I try to update the module